# Функция для массива в JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Функция должна найти минимальную сумму num элементов из значений массива array.

Пример значений переменных:

```
array = [2, 4, 7, 8, 1]
num = 2
```

Пример результата:

```
3
```

Условие:

> В программе задан массив array, элементы которого имеют численное значение, и переменная num, которая является числом. Реализуйте функцию queue(num, ...array), которая принимает в качестве аргументов множество значений списка array и значение переменной num. Функция должна найти минимальную сумму num элементов из значений массива array. Ответ выведите в консоль.

Код:

```
const queue = (numsCount, ...arr) => {
  const array = arr[0];
  let nums = new Array(numsCount).fill(Infinity);
  array.forEach(num => {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
      if (nums[i] <= num) continue;
      nums.splice(i, 0, num);
      nums.pop();
      break;
    }
  });
  nums = nums.map(x => x === Infinity ? 0 : x);
  const sum = nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  console.log(sum);
}
```

также пробовал и:

```
function queue (numsCount, ...arr) {
  const array = arr[0];
  let nums = new Array(numsCount).fill(Infinity);

  array.forEach(num => {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
      if (nums[i] <= num) continue;

      nums.splice(i, 0, num);
      nums.pop();
      break;
    }
  });

  nums = nums.map(x => x === Infinity ? 0 : x);

  const sum = nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  
  console.log(sum);
}
```

`queue(num, array)` отрабатывает, а `queue(num, ...array)` выдает:

```
Uncaught TypeError: array.forEach is not a function
    at queue (<anonymous>:5:9)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: Гарантировано что `num` будет целым, неотрицатетльным и всегда меньше или равно чем `array.length`? Или массив может иметь любую длину и `num` может абсолютно любым числом?

Comment: Да, num >= 0 && num < array
Массив не длиннее 5

Comment: замени на `function queue(num, ...arr){`

Comment: ну и так как `num` не изменяется - сейчас цикл бесконечный

Comment: Да, тут не написал, но в каждой итерации цикла num--

Comment: Разве минимальная сумма n чисел это не будет просто сумма первым n чисел в массиве (предварительно отсортированного, конечно)?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой алгоритм:

1. Создаём пустой массив `nums`, куда будем записывать по одному числа из оригинального массива
2. Объявляем `sum`, где будем сразу считать получившуюся сумму, чтобы потом в лишний раз не проходиться по всем элементам `nums`
3. Пробегаем по всем элементам оригинального массива и смотрим куда в `nums` можно пристроить очередной элемент `num`

   3.1. Т.к. нам нужна минимальная сумма, то мы как только в массиве `nums` находим элемент, который больше чем `num`, заменяем его на `nums[i]` или же вставляем в конец массива, если длина `nums` ещё не дошла до своего предела. Таким образом мы гарантированно считаем минимальную сумму + элементы всегда будут упорядочены он меньшего к большему

   3.2. Если индекс элемента, оказался равным количеству элементов, которое требовалось найти, то по идее мы должны были поместить его в конец массива, но т.к. количество элементов `nums` не может превышать `numsCount`, нам сразу после этого пришлось бы удалить этот элемент из массива. По этой причине, чтобы не делать лишних добавлений и удалений я просто прекращаю выполнение функции

   3.3. В противном случае Я добавляю в массив элемент и за одно его сразу добавляю к общей сумме. Если после добавления длина `nums` будет превышать лимит `numsCount`, то значит нам нужно последний элемент из массива удалить, т.к. очевидно, что он будет наибольшим, а значит его же и надо вычесть из общей суммы, т.к. мы его до этого туда добавляли
4. Мы возвращаем получившуюся сумму

```js
const findMinSum = (numsCount, ...arr) => {
  const nums = [];
  let sum = 0;

  arr.forEach(num => {
    let i = 0;
    
    for (; i < nums.length; ++i) {
      if (nums[i] > num) break;
    }
    
    // or you can replace `for` with this `while`
    // while (i < nums.length && nums[i++] <= num);
    
    if (i === numsCount) return;
    
    nums.splice(i, 0, num);
    sum += num;
    
    if (nums.length > numsCount) sum -= nums.pop();
  });
  
  return sum;
}

const array = [2, 4, 7, 8, 1];
const num = 2;

console.log(findMinSum(num, ...array));
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150086/discussion-on-answer-by-eziomercer-----js); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function queue(num, ...array) {
  let sortArr = array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let result = sortArr.reduce((acc, n) => {
    if (acc.counter < num) {
      acc.counter++;
      acc.sum += n;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {
    counter: 0,
    sum: 0
  });
  console.log(result.sum)
};

let array = [2, 4, 7, 8, 1];
let num = 2;

queue(num, ...array);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: зачем бежать reduce по всем элементам, если ты сразу знаешь сколько элементов тебе нужно?